# SQL: insert into 3 tables with a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add data to 3 tables. The table "Gebruiker" is the parent table. 
Wen i use the following code it gives me the follow error:

My SQL code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Gebruiker
INNER JOIN Inlog
ON Gebruiker.idGebruiker=Inlog.Gebruiker_idGebruiker
INNER JOIN GGevens
ON Gebruiker.idGebruiker=GGevens.Gebruiker_idGebruiker
INNER JOIN Domein
ON Gebruiker.Domein_idDomeint=Domein.idDomeint;
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO Gebruiker (Domein_idDomeint,idGebruiker)
VALUES (1,NULL);

INSERT INTO Inlog (Gebruiker_idGebruiker,UserName,UserPass)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'profile','drie');

INSERT INTO GGevens (Gebruiker_idGebruiker,Email,Voornaam,Tussenvoeg,Achternaam,Geslacht,Opleiding,GebDatum)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'aapje@peer.nl','Aapje','van','Drie',1,'Zeerslim','2014-11-11');
COMMIT;
```

Error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`zolstm001`.`GGevens`, CONSTRAINT `fk_GGevens_Gebruiker1` FOREIGN KEY (`Gebruiker_idGebruiker`) REFERENCES `Gebruiker` (`idGebruiker`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

My database structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Vdn.png

I think its because the table "GGevens" needs a foreign key from the table "Gebruiker"

Does someone know how i can add this?

(LAST_INSERT_ID() does not work...

SQL code to create the tables:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema zolstm001
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema zolstm001
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `zolstm001` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `zolstm001` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `zolstm001`.`Domein`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zolstm001`.`Domein` (
  `idDomeint` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Naam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `OverigeGegevens` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDomeint`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `zolstm001`.`Gebruiker`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zolstm001`.`Gebruiker` (
  `idGebruiker` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Domein_idDomeint` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idGebruiker`),
  INDEX `fk_Gebruiker_Domein1_idx` (`Domein_idDomeint` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Gebruiker_Domein1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Domein_idDomeint`)
    REFERENCES `zolstm001`.`Domein` (`idDomeint`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `zolstm001`.`GGevens`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zolstm001`.`GGevens` (
  `idGGevens` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Gebruiker_idGebruiker` INT NOT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `GebDatum` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idGGevens`),
  INDEX `fk_GGevens_Gebruiker1_idx` (`Gebruiker_idGebruiker` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_GGevens_Gebruiker1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Gebruiker_idGebruiker`)
    REFERENCES `zolstm001`.`Gebruiker` (`idGebruiker`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `zolstm001`.`Inlog`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zolstm001`.`Inlog` (
  `idInlog` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `UserPass` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Gebruiker_idGebruiker` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idInlog`),
  INDEX `fk_Inlog_Gebruiker1_idx` (`Gebruiker_idGebruiker` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Inlog_Gebruiker1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Gebruiker_idGebruiker`)
    REFERENCES `zolstm001`.`Gebruiker` (`idGebruiker`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `zolstm001`.`Startup`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zolstm001`.`Startup` (
  `idStartup` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Naam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Gebruiker_idGebruiker` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idStartup`),
  INDEX `fk_Startup_Gebruiker1_idx` (`Gebruiker_idGebruiker` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Startup_Gebruiker1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Gebruiker_idGebruiker`)
    REFERENCES `zolstm001`.`Gebruiker` (`idGebruiker`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `zolstm001`.`Reactie`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zolstm001`.`Reactie` (
  `idReactie` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Gebruiker_idGebruiker` INT NOT NULL,
  `Bericht` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Startup_idStartup` INT NOT NULL,
  `Reactiecol` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idReactie`),
  INDEX `fk_Reactie_Gebruiker1_idx` (`Gebruiker_idGebruiker` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Reactie_Startup1_idx` (`Startup_idStartup` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Reactie_Gebruiker1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Gebruiker_idGebruiker`)
    REFERENCES `zolstm001`.`Gebruiker` (`idGebruiker`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Reactie_Startup1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Startup_idStartup`)
    REFERENCES `zolstm001`.`Startup` (`idStartup`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `zolstm001`.`Category`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zolstm001`.`Category` (
  `idCategory` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Startup_idStartup` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCategory`),
  INDEX `fk_Category_Startup1_idx` (`Startup_idStartup` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Category_Startup1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Startup_idStartup`)
    REFERENCES `zolstm001`.`Startup` (`idStartup`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `zolstm001`.`Unit`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zolstm001`.`Unit` (
  `idUnit` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Startup_idStartup` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUnit`),
  INDEX `fk_Unit_Startup1_idx` (`Startup_idStartup` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Unit_Startup1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Startup_idStartup`)
    REFERENCES `zolstm001`.`Startup` (`idStartup`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `zolstm001`.`SGegevens`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zolstm001`.`SGegevens` (
  `idSGegevens` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Startup_idStartup` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idSGegevens`),
  INDEX `fk_SGegevens_Startup1_idx` (`Startup_idStartup` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_SGegevens_Startup1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Startup_idStartup`)
    REFERENCES `zolstm001`.`Startup` (`idStartup`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: THe problem could be in Gebruiker. You are inserting a NULL for idGebruiker. Do you have an auto_increment with a NOT NULL constraint on that column? Can you also post the create table statements (instead of the imgur screenshot)?

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` changes to the value of `idinlog` when you insert to `Inlog`. You could store the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in a variable after inserting to `Gebruiker` and reference that in both subsequent inserts.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen added ^

Comment: idGebruiker is an "AI", i thought NULL was needed to get ":AST_INSERT_ID()" working?

Comment: @dartonw is it possible to save a variable in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the INSERT INTO gebruiker to 
    INSERT INTO Gebruiker (Domein_idDomeint) VALUES (1);

Furthermore to get this working, you will need to use some programming code to help you. This can be done in the shape of a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE gebruikerProc (IN {your_params})
BEGIN 
DECLARE lastId INT;
INSERT INTO Gebruiker (Domein_idDomeint) VALUES (1);
SET lastId=LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO Inlog (Gebruiker_idGebruiker,UserName,UserPass)
VALUES (lastId,'profile','drie');

INSERT INTO GGevens (Gebruiker_idGebruiker,Email,Voornaam,Tussenvoeg,Achternaam,Geslacht,Opleiding,GebDatum)
VALUES (lastId,'aapje@peer.nl','Aapje','van','Drie',1,'Zeerslim','2014-11-11');
END;
```

One warning: Do not use TAB to indent your code in a stored procedure/function/trigger etc in MySQL. You will get an error. It just can not handle TAB.

Comment: Hi thx for helping! @NorbertvanNobelen

I did not work before with stored procedures. 
What should be filled in on the place "(IN {**your_params**})" ? :-)

Comment: All your input parameters like "IN Domein_idDomeint INT" etc.. See for example http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures-in-mysql-5--net-17843 for a quick manual.

Comment: Okay, and do you know how to define multiple params? Since i have more than one. Is this a correct example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067817/stored-procedure-with-multiple-in-parameter

Comment: I get a SQL syntax error when i use "DECLARE lastId INT;"    Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/ab1SGtU.png

Comment: Fixed it by deleting the ";"